# Call native JNI DLL from C#

Tags: java, c#, dll, java-native-interface

I have a native DLL `abc.dll` (without source code) that was originally used in a JNI call in Java like this:

```
public class ABC_Proxy
{
    private native void callABC(String parameter);

    public ABC_Proxy()
    {
        System.loadLibrary("abc");
    }

    public void Start(String paramater)
    {
        callABC(paramater);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to execute the same function in C#. Using *dumpbin* I found the correct full entry point, and this is what I came up with so far:

```
class Abc
{
    [DllImport("abc.dll", EntryPoint="_Java_my_namespace_abc_1Proxy_callABC@12")]
    private static extern void CallAbc(string parameter);

    public void Start(string parameter)
    {
        CallAbc("test");
    }
}
```

I can see that `CallAbc` is executed and does something (it creates a file) but then it throws an `AccessViolationException`, presumably when it tries to access the parameter.

The [PureDLLHelper](http://www.purebasic.fr/english/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=45226) suggests that the function has 3 parameters, and after reading [this JNI tutorial](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=334) I have the feeling that I also need to pass the parameters `JNIEnv*, jobject` to simulate a JNI call. But from here on I'm lost...

Any idea? Is it even possible what I'm trying to achieve?

**Edit:** I just want to mention [this forum post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/325/native-library-integration) that has a good explanation of the problems involved and how they *could* by solved. However, the solutions are based on *Xamarin.Android* to bridge the C#/Java gap and get hold of the JNIEnv, which is not really an option for me.

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you help you are trying to get on SO. Since the only thing you are looking for is to be able to call a function it is *theoretically* possible. Would it be good idea - likely not, especially since you have no source/supported way to call it. You may want to either consider it educational exercise and build your own native library to learn on. You will know what fails and will be able to make this question more generic but with complete code. Alternatively drop this idea altogether as it will likely cause you even more pain in the future.

Comment: You don't need to simulate a JNI call. What is the declaration of that function you want to call in abc.dll?

Comment: @Matt You have all the information I have, including the working Java call from which I hoped the declaration can be derived. Considering the tutorial I mentioned, the real declaration is probably `JNIEXPORT void JNICALL _Java_my_namespace_abc_1Proxy_callABC@12 (JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring);`

Comment: @Doug, I'm confused. You said the abc.dll is the DLL which is used by JNI dll, but this should be the function declaration in the JNI dll.

Comment: @matt No, `abc.dll` *is* the JNI dll, and it also includes the business logic. There is no other. I said "used in a JNI call" not "in a[nother] JNI dll".

Comment: @Doug, JNI dll is served as a wrapper to call C/C++ DLL, should not include business logic there.

Comment: @Matt Well, in my case it does, unfortunately. And given that the business logic is probably just a few lines, and this all was a custom development, and even the linked tutorial promotes exactly that approach, I can see why it was done like this. Either way, these are the prerequisites I have to deal with.

Comment: "get hold of the JNIEnv, which is not really an option for me" Why not? You want to use code that runs in a JVM; Create one.

Answer (score 0):

Its not going to work, simple as that.  The JNI DLL is designed and built to be loaded by the JVM.  You will not be able to provide the pointers to the env or jvm that are required to call any of the functions contained in that library.  Your only option would be to create a second DLL that creates a new instance of the JVM that then calls the DLL you have, but if you are calling Java from .Net, you may as well keep it all in Java.